# Autocomplete textbox is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a auto complete textbox. I wrote a php code to get list of values from an API using httpful. below is the php code to list out the values.

```
     ->send();
   $json = $dt_response;
   $json_output = json_decode($json, true);
     for($i=0;$i<count($json_output);$i++)
      {
             echo $json_output[$i]['tracker_id'].'<br />';
      }
```

Below is the javascript code to call the above code from search.php file.

```
     <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#trackid" ).autocomplete({
                source: 'search.php'
            });
        });

            </script>
```

HTML of textbox:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
     <label for="trackid">Tracker ID: </label>
     <input id="trackid">
    </div>
```

The problem is when i trying to type the value in the textbox it doesn't drop down the value. I checked my php code its working fine. All the files are in the same folder. What is the problem?

Comment: Did you test your `search.php` file on it's own? I'm pretty sure you get some errors here. And you're mixing json with html. And the return should be a json, not a string, I guess (without knowing autocomplete).

Comment: Hi @Jeff. Thanks for the reply. Ya i check my php code. I think my php output is json decoded data. Where i mixing json with html.

Comment: please use this example [ink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341424/php-mysql-autocomplete-does-not-working/37342012#37342012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the below php code on start.

```
<?php 
  require_once('search.php');
?>
```

and changed my javascript code to

```
<script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#trackid" ).autocomplete({
  source: <?php print_r(json_encode($options)); ?>
  });
  });
</script>
```

Slightly changed my search.php code.

```
 ->send();
 $json = $dt_response;
 $json_output = json_decode($json, true);

 for($i=0;$i<count($json_output);$i++)
    {
        $trackerid[$i]=$json_output[$i]['tracker_id'];
    }
$options = $trackerid;
```

Now its working fine.